# can't declare var a = 023; in js

Tags: javascript

I want to declare

```js
var a = 0213;
document.write(a);
```

but it not work .when console.log(a); variable 
different.

Comment: Judging by the leading zero, you are giving your number in octal, right?

Comment: That's an octal literal, remove the `0` in the start and it'll work.

Comment: If you can't leave off the leading `0`, you can do: Number(a.toString())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers with a leading `0` are [interpreted as octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers) (base 8).

Octal `0213` == decimal `139`.

If you need the value `213` (decimal), leave off the leading `0`.